# Keep on sort order when using IN statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, where-in

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

I have a temporary sorted table (`Table_A`) that contains 2 columns (`ID`, `RowNumber`).
Now, I create a new table by selecting all rows from other table (`Table_B`) that exist (`ID` value) in the temporary table (`Table_A`).

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_B
WHERE Table_B.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table_A)
```

The results of the query above is not sorted by `Table_A` sorting.
I'm looking for a way to keep the results of the new result table sorted by the `Table_A` sorting.

Tx....

Comment: Tables aren't sorted - only result sets (and cursors) are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a `JOIN` instead. I have assumed below that `Table_A` can only have 1 row per `ID`. If this is not the case then rewriting as a `JOIN` will introduce duplicate rows and we will need more details of which `RowNumber` to use for sorting purposes in that case.

```
SELECT Table_B.* 
FROM Table_B JOIN Table_A ON  Table_B.ID = Table_A.ID
ORDER BY Table_A.RowNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

select b.* from Table_B b
   join Table_A a on a.id = b.id
   order by a.RowNumber